# Strange sounding instruction - I found you X

Tags: grammar, writing

Trying to create a notification message for a user on a website.

Right now, the flow is that following some search, results are presented to a user with text such as:

"I Found you these great results !"

I understand this can be changed to "Here are some ... "

But what I am really trying to understand is if this is a legit usage of language:
I found you X

I am of course a non native, so maybe the "strangeness" is just to my ears..

Comment: 'I found you X' also has the meaning 'My impression of you was that you are X' so you have to be a bit careful with the phrasing - if the user searches for 'boring' then telling them that 'I found you boring!' wouldn't go down well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's perfectly grammatical.

In the same way that ditransitive verbs (like *give* and *show*) can be used in two ways,

> I gave the book to her.

or

> I gave her the book.

many verbs can have a benefactive "for X", which can be treated the same way:

> I baked a cake for her.

or

> I baked her a cake.

So "I found you this" is identical in meaning to "I found this for you".

To me, this is something that would be said by a friend, or a person who had been working with me and established some sort of relationship. To have a piece of software say it strikes me as presumptuous, trying to pretend that it has a personal relationship with me.

Comment: _"[..] trying to pretend that it has a personal relationship with me"_. This may well be the point. Many companies adopt this approach as an attempt to be user friendly, although it is not to everyone's taste. See also [wackaging](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/wordofmouth/2014/mar/25/wackaging-trend-food-packaging-innocent-language)

Comment: To me, "I found you this" is slightly different from "I found this for you". The latter suggests you might have asked me to find it, or I was searching intentionally for some reason. In the former case I could have stumbled upon something at a thrift store and I got it because I knew you'd like it. But of course this is a very subtle and questionable shade of meaning; broadly the two phrases are very similar.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of usage of an [indirect object](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/indirectobject.htm). This often happens with the preposition **to**;

> I gave the book **to you**
>   I gave **you** the book

Note that the indirect object **you** can follow the direct object **the book**, with the preposition **to**, or it can follow the verb and lose the preposition. This also happens *occasionally* with the preposition **for**

> I found these great results **for you**!
>   I found **you** these great results!